# LDAP replace a list values for one attribute

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I have an attribute, like `telephonenumber`, which appears several times on a person. Now I want to replace all numbers by a list of new numbers:

```
<person>  
<telephonnumber>12345</telephonnumber>  
<telephonnumber>23456</telephonnumber>  
</person>
```

replace by:

```
<person>  
<telephonnumber>56789</telephonnumber>  
<telephonnumber>78901</telephonnumber>  
</person>
```

How can I do this in Java?

Using

```
mods.add(new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("telephonnumber", "56789")));  
mods.add(new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("telephonnumber", "78901")));
```

ends up with all values will be replaced by the last ModificationItem. Well I could work around by removing all number, and adding all new values from the list. But I think Java LDAP supports it directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to create a ***single*** replace with your multi-valued telephone attribute.  See the [Oracle LDAP attributes tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/misc/attrs.html).

```
// Create a multivalued attribute that has four String values
BasicAttribute oc = new BasicAttribute("objectClass", "top");
oc.add("person");
oc.add("organizationalPerson");
oc.add("inetOrgPerson");
```

Tip: First try out your LDAP operations via an [LDIF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2849) file before you start coding.